# What are those two lights in the sky?

Tags: plot-explanation, army-of-the-dead

In the opening sequence of the movie Army of the Dead, we see two light dots in the sky that just fly off the screen at an enormous speed as the Four Horsemen convoy is leaving the base.

[image: dots idle]

[image: dots flying]

[image: gif]

What are they?

Comment: Let's face it, everyone's thinking zombie UFOs.

Comment: Considering "Robot zombies" and time travel sub-plot in the movie universe this shouldn't be a surprise that those are probably aliens/UFOs. Papa Snyder trying to include as many as subplots possible in a single movie.

Comment: https://www.polygon.com/movies/22435499/army-of-the-dead-2-ending-sequel-scene-zack-synder-interview - He appears to be playing with the audience, including weird easter eggs and nonsense just to get hype